# Regex for matching nested (but not single) braces?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to construct a regex that will match nested braces but not match single braces.

For example given this string:

```
" { { I'm so cool, I'm nested  } } I'm neither { I'm just boring normal braces } "
```

The regex should match:

```
{ { I'm so cool, I'm nested  } }
```

But not:

```
{ I'm just boring normal braces }
```

I think I'm almost there, I been playing around on regex tester to try and make it work, however I must be missing something.

This is what I got so far:

```
(?(?=\{(?>[^\{\}]++|(?R))*\})(\{(?>[^\{\}]++|(?R))*\}))
```

It still matches singles though.

The idea is that it uses an if statement with a positive lookahead to check whether there are nested braces. If there are it matches them. I can't figure out how to exclude regular ones though.

Comment: What should happen when you have `{ { I'm so cool, {I'm super nested}  } }` as input? Also what about `{ { I'm so cool, { {I'm mega nested} }  } }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group it and get match at index 1.

```
({\s*{+.*?}+\s*})
```

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lI3pV9)

Comment: you can  use `\s*` if there are zero or more space between {

Answer (score 0):

This should work for exactly 2nd level nested curlies:

```
{[^{}]*{([^}]*)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
{\s*{.*?}\s*}
```

http://regex101.com/r/zA1bP2

Comment: Oops, looks like @Braj beat me to it. :)

Comment: I edited the pattern to make it ungreedy. Otherwise it would [fail](http://regex101.com/r/uO4aI1)

Comment: Thanx! The original would match what he was trying to do, but the ungreedy version is probably what he really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
({( ?){ ( ?)(.*) ( ?)}( ?)})
```

Matches the string that you are looking for. It also doesn't matter if there are spaces between the brackets or not with this one.

Demo at [Regexr](http://regexr.com/391dr)

Answer (score 0):

You current pattern seems to work fine for me on Regex101. It doesn't match the singles ! But I was able to summarize it for you to this:

```
(\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))++\})
```

You don't really need the if.